# Why does wrapping a layer removes the kernel attribute of another layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am currently creating a LSTM-based network for time series forecasting and I wanted to try to use Keras' `Bidirectional` wrapper to see if it could increase my accuracy.

However, adding the wrapper causes my output layer to lose its `kernel` attribute, which is problematic as my optimizer tries to access it, resulting in a crash during compilation time.

That is to say, when I do:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(
    100,
    batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, features),
))
model.add(Dense(1))

print(hasattr(model.layers[-1], 'kernel'))
```

> True

But when wrapping the LSTM like so:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(
    100,
    batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, features),
)))
model.add(Dense(1))

print(hasattr(model.layers[-1], 'kernel'))
```

> False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to have your network predict something, then compile it with your custom optimizer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(
    100,
    batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, features),
)))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.predict(np.zeros((batch_size, look_back, features)))
print(hasattr(model.layers[-1], 'kernel'))
model.compile(optimizer=CustomOptimizer(), loss='mse')
```

> True

Comment: Not necessary to compile for prediction